# Hand Scanner using DB9

Tags: scanner

I am new to Ubuntu so I hope this is a good place to ask for help.

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to get a Honeywell 1980i hand barcode scanner to work through Serial DB9 cable.  My searches on-line have not been successful to get it to work even though everyone seems to get softwedges to work without issue.

Does anyone have any steps or tips for someone starting out with linux on how to get this to work.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/Do-Honeywell-hand-held-scanners-interface-with-Linux  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: For details see the PDF in the link posted by @chili555 https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/servlet/fileField?entityId=ka02K000000caZsQAI&field=File_1__Body__s

Answer (score 0):

I worked with these every day. The problem, 9 times out of ten is the USB to serial adapter.

If Linux cannot see or use that, you are dead in the water. Find a brand that works and stick to it. There are too many crappy adapters out there that do not work with Linux. Also make sure the scanner is set to serial if need be, do a reset and set it up gain. You can always test by taking out the serial cable and putting in a USB one (iirc the 1980's have a RJ45 connector on the other end) and plug it into your Ubuntu machine. Use dmesg to see if it got detected via USB, if it is, swap your cables back and see if the USB to serial adapter was detected. Just eliminate potential issues and continue.